# Show iframes in angular-xeditable editables

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe, x-editable

I'm using angular-xeditable, here is my editable element:

```
<div class="like-pre" editable-textarea="question.answer" e-rows="10" e-cols="40" onbeforesave="validateFaq($data, 'answer')" ng-bind-html="question.answer"></div>
```

In controller, I use $sce.trustAsHtml to make question.answer appear as regular HTML instead of raw text. HTML can contain iframe (for youtube videos) or img elements. **It works.**

Problem is that after I change anything in question.answer through the editable element, IFRAME elements disappears complately. IMG elements still appears correctly after edition.

Anyone have idea whats wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. Problem was that xeditable only updates model data. After model is updated, it update editable div element through angulars bindings. Iframe was not shown, because new model content was not signed as trusted.

I had tried pass question.answer variable through $sce.trustAsHtml in onaftersave, but it didnt do anything. Thats because trustAsHtml didnt changed anything, I suppose it just marked it as trusted (dont know how it works internally).

Solution was adding empty space like this:

```
$sce.trustAsHtml(newQuestion.answer + ' ');
```

So angular finds that model has been changed and reloads editabel div with new - trusted as html - content.